# How to show maps inside tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to android and have no experience of Java either.
I am making an application that has tabs. One of the tabs, when clicked must show googlemap. I was successful doing that, the problem is when the map is displayed, it does not show the tab so i could not return to other tabs. the purpose of the other tabs is to display the location of that were selected on the mapview. could anyone help me with this? below are my codes

**MainActivity.java**

```
package jp.co.gpsloader;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ActivityGroup;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
    //Used Activity group because tabhost was used ActivityGroup
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public class MainActivity extends ActivityGroup {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Then do Main Activity name
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_tab_layout);
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        // Then added an Intent on our new tab
        TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Location");
        spec2.setIndicator("Location");
        spec2.setContent(new Intent(this, SampleMapClickListener.class));

        TabSpec spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("The GPS");
        spec3.setIndicator("The GPS");
        spec3.setContent(new Intent(this, GpsMain.class));


        Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, GpsMain.class);
        spec3.setContent(i);

        // Add your new tab in the tabhost here
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);

        // This is needed for Activity group
        tabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

**GPSMain.java**

```
package jp.co.gpsloader;

import android.os.*;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;      
import com.google.android.gms.internal.v;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;

public class GpsMain extends Activity {
MapFragment mf;
GoogleMap gm;
MarkerOptions marker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mf = MapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, mf);
    ft.commit();
}
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // created map
    gm = mf.getMap();
    gm.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    gm.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // set latitude and longitude
    LatLng ltn = new LatLng(40, 135);

    // create marker
    marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.position(ltn);

    // operation can be done, when click happens
    gm.setOnMapClickListener(new SampleMapClickListener());
}

class SampleMapClickListener implements OnMapClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng ltn) {
        marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.position(ltn);
        gm = mf.getMap();
        // add marker
        gm.addMarker(marker);

    }

}
```

}

**activity_android_tab_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
/>
 <FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
 >
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
 >
 <TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="100px" 
android:text="This is tab1"
android:id="@+id/txt1"
/>    

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tab2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
 >
 <TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="100px" 
android:text="This is tab 2"
android:id="@+id/txt2"
/>

 </LinearLayout>


 </FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

**map.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post related codes only ? You pasted almost everything.

Comment: I tried editing the codes. i just couldnt edit activity_android_tab_layout.xml. im not so sure which ones are important.

Answer (score 0):

On your activity_android_tab_layout.xml TabWidget, assign a height, lets say 50dp:

```
        android:layout_height="50dp"
```

On your map.xml, assign a marginBottom, also 50dp:

```
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
```